# how to change the location of all keyframes in blender timeline at once

Tags: animation, keyframes, timeline

I have an animation that has 129 frames. My problem is that the rotation and location of the object are not right.

I want to change the location and rotation of all 129 frames at once. 
I tried setting them one by one to each frame but it takes some time.

The location that I'm looking to apply is (G + X + 2) and the rotation is (R + Z + 3.5).

Gratefully Amirreza.

Comment: I'd recommend to use an empty and parent the entire part you want to change to it. Then you can move and/or rotate the empty and the entire animation will be adjusted/offset that way.

Comment: have you tried with the Graph Editor? Select the curve you need to change and move it manually or with a value + enter

Comment: ... and in the graph editor a keyframe is a (frame, value) pair where  x is frames, and y is value.  To add 1 to all x location keyframe values, select the curve and all its keyframes GY1.  To shift forward in timeline 1 frame GX1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the *Graph Editor*:

- Enable the *Only Show Selected* option (little arrow button) so that you'll only see the curve related to the selected object.
- Select your object in the 3D view, unfold the tracks in the *Graph Editor*.
- Lock all the locks. Only open the one you want. Or select the track you want and <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> to hide all the others (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> to unhide). Or use the search field to only display the wanted tracks.
- Select the curve and move it manually or with the value you want, then <kbd>Enter</kbd>. To move the curve vertically press <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd>, horizontally press <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>

[image]

Comment: thank you for the answer, even though that the version of the blender that i'm using is slightly different than the one you're using in this picture (mine is after 2.8) but it was a great solution.
I locked everything except the one that i wanted to change, double A + G and moved it and it appied to every frame. simple as that ♥